How do I recover disk/system that won't boot with "device offline", "I/O error"?
This is from a Raspberry Pi 4 that, until last night, was running as a Plex server.
It suddenly died last night, couldn't connect via SSH. I tried rebooting manually (headless) hoping that helped. It didn't.
I eventually got it connected to a monitor and after several power cycles I eventually got to this. Interestingly, if I boot it now, it just displays a rainbow screen which is odd.
The Raspberry Pi OS is on a few month old 2TB M.2 SSD (in an Argon M.2 case, in case that matters). It's using the original power supply.
Two questions:

Can I recover the whole system?
Can I recover the data (i.e. media) on the drive?


(Sorry for the photo, it was the only option.)

Perhaps it's time to accept that the drive is dying / dead? The time length it lived doesn't necessarily matter. (It could be the enclosure / cable / ... as well, if you have spare hardware and PC, you may try to confirm with them.)

It's a brand new drive, bought in February 2024... Seems an unreasonably short time for an SSD to live, no?

Not really. They (any kind of drives, really) don't have to die of "weariness".
